# How to get dial pad beep sound on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uibutton

How to get dial pad beep sound on iOS 7.

I have a dialpad in my app and would like to use iOS 7 dial pad sound.The one like the figure
[image]

I tried some other methods but was not proper and sound won't get reduced at time of muting the device.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

One can use the following simple sound trick.

```
NSUInteger toneID = 1200 + value;
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound((SystemSoundID)toneID);
```

Here `value` is a number from 0 to 11.

0-9 are for keypad digits, 10 is for star, 11 is for hash.

Note that Apple accepts this code in AppStore without any problems. A number of my applications lives on AppStore from 2014 till now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all import .wav audio files 0 to 9 in audio box and name them properly like i wrote code here for files like DTMF_00.wav to DTMF_09.wav so you have to named this file as your wish but keep in mind that you have to change `NSString *toneFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DTMF_%02d", count];` this line and give your file names.

and then you have to `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` both in viewController.h

in .h file declare `SystemSoundID toneSSIDs[10];` in { } of interface like this

`@interface yourViewController : UIViewController{
    SystemSoundID toneSSIDs[10];
}`

set an button action event in header file and set it to all button.(keep in mind don't create action events for individual you have to create only one click event)

then you have to write this code on .m file above or below `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {

        for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++){
            NSString *toneFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DTMF_%02d", count];

            NSURL *toneURLRef = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:toneFilename withExtension:@"wav"];

            SystemSoundID toneSSID = 0;

            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) toneURLRef,&toneSSID);
            toneSSIDs[count] = toneSSID;
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

then

```
-(IBAction)numberButtonPressed:(UIButton *)pressedButton
{
    int toneIndex = [pressedButton.titleLabel.text intValue];
    SystemSoundID toneSSID = toneSSIDs[toneIndex];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(toneSSID);
}
```

Comment: will apple block my app if i use system sounds?

Comment: I am not sure buddy but Apple may reject your app. Means you have to do changes as Apple gives and again you have to submit app in which you done changes... And read apple's instruction for more detail..

Answer (score 0):

## Plays a system sound - Swift 5.9 +

```
@IBAction func btnDialPadNumberTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Play built-in iPhone DialPad Sound
    let toneID = UInt(1200 + sender.tag)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(toneID))
}
```

It utilizes the system's built-in sound functionality, where, for example, pressing **number 1** corresponds to the sound ID 1201. Internally, this code is linked to a particular sound file, such as "dtmf-1.caf," which is used for the digit 1.

See list of predefined iPhone sounds that can be used with AudioServices [iPhone Development Wiki](https://iphonedev.wiki/AudioServices).
For further information lookup Apple Docs: [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405248-audioservicesplaysystemsound)